# On conflict do nothing clause is ignored on bulk insert

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, sql-insert, bulkinsert

Only products which exist in product table should be added to price list.

Script

```
update pricelistnew set timestamp=to_char(now(), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS');

truncate pricelist;

insert into pricelist
select * from pricelistnew
on conflict do nothing;
```

throws error

> ERROR: insert or update on table "pricelist" violates foreign key
> constraint "pricelist_product_fkey"
> DETAIL: Key
> (product)=(TMMEM0EM00691BDS    ) is not present in table "product".

Script with additional foreign key check

```
insert into pricelist
select * from pricelistnew
where product in (select product  from product)
on conflict do nothing;
```

worked.

Why `on conflict do nothing` clause is ignored ?
How to add only products where match to foreign key without using additional check

```
product in (select product  from product )
```

Price list has 300000 rows and this command takes several minutes to complete on fast server. It locks tables so that other queries running same time are delayed. How to do this bulk insert efficiently ?

Using

PostgreSQL 13.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1900, 64-bit

**Update**

Table structures:

```
create table product (
   product char(20) primary key );

create table pricelist ( product char(20) references product on update cascade on delete cascade deferrable, 
timestamp char(14), 
price numeric(12,2) );

create table pricelistnew ( product char(20) , timestamp char(14), 
price numeric(12,2) );
```

Comment: `on conflict` **only** deals with violations of unique constraints.

Comment: If product is deleted from product table in other transaction during insert, script with `where product in (select product  from product)` still fails. How to fix this without running every single insert in separate transaction?

Comment: @Andrus Please post your table structure also.

Comment: Updated question and added table structures